# add existing content type to document library

Tags: content-type

I get error message when I click on "Add from existing site content types"
I want to add existing content type to this document library. Is there any powershell script for the same. Content type is already added in site but when i edit document properties it does not show 1 content type.

My document library name is "ABC"
Content type name is "XYZ"

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Unexpected error, I checked ULS log but could not get rid of error. Do you have idea how to overcome this?

Comment: Which version of Sharepoint?

Comment: sharepoint 2010

Comment: When you get the error , do you get a correlation id?

Comment: 9212135c-07e6-4cef-b8c4-96cba5e72918

Comment: check the logs for the correlation id. Check this article it helps http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-find-error-messages-with-a-correlation-id-token-in-sharepoint-2010 . Let me know what exactly the issue is?

Comment: I checked correlation ID and ULS log say "no two choice column should have same ID" . I have more than 150 site columns and cannot get duplicate field. Can you provide me any script which can check duplicate field and specially remove it or change its guid of duplicate fields. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following PS script should help:

```
#Get site object and specify name of the library to look for in each site
$site = Get-SPSite http://portal
$lookForList = "ABC"

#Walk through each site and change content types on the list specified
$siteA = $site.OpenWeb("http://portal/sites/A")

    write-host "Checking site:" $siteA.Title

    #Make sure content types are allowed on the list specified
    $docLibrary = $siteA.Lists[$lookForList]

    if ($docLibrary -ne $null)
    {
        $docLibrary.ContentTypesEnabled = $true
        $docLibrary.Update()

        #Add site content types to the list
        $ctToAdd = $siteA.ContentTypes["XYZ"]
        $ct = $docLibrary.ContentTypes.Add($ctToAdd)
        write-host "Content type" $ct.Name "added to list" $docLibrary.Title
        $docLibrary.Update()
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "The list" $lookForList "does not exist in site" $siteA.Title
    }


#Dispose of the site object
$site.Dispose()
```

But you should check the error you get when you navigate to Add from existing content type.. Get the correlation and check the exact error in ULS logs

Comment: ULS log just giving that there is error while adding existing content type... any solution how to overcome this??

Comment: In site collection there are many site which has same library name, i don't want to go through each site and library. So can i use below?

Comment: So you want to add the content type in each library in each site?

Comment: Updated the script to work for all sites within a site collection

Comment: No I just want for 1 library, like we have 10 "ABC" library in site collection. I do not want to iterate for each document libray. Just for library "ABC" which is under site A. How to use syntax for open web instead of rootweb?

Comment: Updated the script, use OpenWeb method and pass the URL of site A

Comment: I tried can you make edit in above script and provide new one with openweb()

Comment: I have already updated the script.. see above !

Comment: what is siteA above? 
SiteSiteName  ??

Answer (score 1):

Running Powershell and accessing a Subsite (and not the root web) you have to make a slightly different approach. You need to access the root web content type, and add that one to the subsite document library

```
$SPSite = Get-SPSite "http://portal"
$lookForList = "Shared Documents"

if ($SPSite -ne $null)
{
    foreach ($SPWeb in $SPSite.AllWebs)
    {
        $docLibrary = $SPWeb.Lists[$lookForList]
        $ctInRootWeb = $SPSite.RootWeb.ContentTypes["Company Document"]

        if($docLibrary.ContentTypes["Company Document"].Name -eq "Company Document")
        {
            Write-Host "   CT exist" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }
        else
        {
            $ct = $docLibrary.ContentTypes.Add($ctInRootWeb)
            $docLibrary.Update()
            Write-Host "   CT Added" -ForegroundColor Green
        }

        if ($SPWeb -ne $null)
        {
            $SPWeb.Dispose()
        }
    }
}

if ($SPSite -ne $null)
{
    $SPSite.Dispose()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to visit the http://{sitename}/_layouts/mngfield.aspx

{sitename}- yoursitename to see if there are any duplicate fields are there.and delete accordingly . This site should help you for a detailed step [Link](http://sharepointdiva.wordpress.com/2012/08/16/no-two-choices-should-have-the-same-id/)